# Leaflet Draw - save GeoJSON to server

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet, leaflet-draw

Inspired by this often cited question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211496/leaflet-draw-add-attributes-and-save-to-file
I wanted to do something similar myself, but instead of creating a file for download, I'd like to save it on the server.

I've put something together and I get no errors in the console but the GeoJSON file on the server remains empty. Most likely I'm using the ajax wrong somehow.

I think the critical part of the code is this:

```
    /*
    =============================================================================
    Open Editable Popup
    =============================================================================
    */

    map.on('draw:created', function (event) {
      var layer = event.layer,
          feature = layer.feature = layer.feature || {}; // Intialize layer.feature
          feature.type = feature.type || "Feature"; // Intialize feature.type
      var props = feature.properties = feature.properties || {}; // Intialize feature.properties
      props.title = "my title";
      props.content = "my content";
      var idIW = L.popup();
      var content = '<span><b>Name</b></span><br/><input id="shapeName" type="text"/><br/><br/><span><b>Description<b/></span><br/><textarea id="shapeDesc" cols="25" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/><input type="button" id="okBtn" value="Save" onclick="saveIdIW()"/>';
      idIW.setContent(content);
      idIW.setLatLng(layer.getLatLng());
      idIW.openOn(map);
      drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
  });


    function saveIdIW() {
        var sName = $('#shapeName').val();
        var sDesc = $('#shapeDesc').val();
        var drawings = drawnItems.getLayers(); //drawnItems is a container for the drawn objects
        drawings[drawings.length - 1].title = sName;
        drawings[drawings.length - 1].content = sDesc;
        map.closePopup();
    };




    /*
    =============================================================================
    Add Button to save the changes to GeoJSON
    =============================================================================
    */

    //button generated by the leaflet easy-button plugin. icon by font awesome - inclusion see html file
    var saveButton = L.easyButton('fa-save', function(btn, map){
            // Extract GeoJson from drawnItems 
            var data = drawnItems.toGeoJSON();
            // Stringify the GeoJson
            var convertedData = 'text/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "data/markers.geojson",   //url of receiver file on server
                data: convertedData,           //data container
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },                              //callback when ajax request finishes
                dataType: "json"                    
              });
    }).addTo(map);
```

Note: this is a fictional map if that makes any difference. But I think at most it should result in wrong point coordinates for the markers, not a completely empty file. 
I post the whole code if you think it helps, but I did not want to make this too long and the rest is basically the code from a previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360207/map-slightly-off-center-with-simple-cartesian-crs-and-tilelayer-in-leaflet plus the leaflet draw controls.

Comment: If you're using jQuery for the `POST` operation, I guess you should just put the data structure as the `data` property of the query, skipping the whole `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(.....))` stuff. Re-read https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType

Comment: hmm... it does not matter wether I use data or convertedData as input - the file remains empty. If I log the contents of data to console, it show a feature collection, but nothing reaches the file. You can check here: http://maps.dungeonmasterresources.com/draw/drawtest.html

Comment: And you've used the network inspector in the browser's developer tools to check that the `POST` operation actually sends the data, right?

Comment: yes, as far as I can see, the date gets send: https://imgur.com/a/QbL6bUF
Could this be somthing on the serverside? Is there any php script needed to recieve the file or such?

Comment: I can't possibly know what's going on serverside.

Comment: Of course not, I was just wondering what the requirements on the server side would be for this to run, so I could check if something is missing and correct it.

Comment: Okay, I've set up a basic lamp stack on a VM and get the same results - a few bytes get transfered but the file remains at 0byte and completely empty. Unless there's more needed on the server side than apache and php, I'm stumped. If I log it to console right before '$.ajax' everything is there and apparently gets transfered but not written to the file.